# Еще одна запятая перед И

Tags: пунктуация

Добрый день! Уважаемые филологи, подскажите, нужна ли запятая перед "и"?
Заметки пишутся не о продуктах, а непосредственно о производителе или бренде и публикуются на авторитетных сайтах.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая перед "и" не нужна, так как этот союз соединяет однородные члены "пишутся" и "публикуются"